# Energy and the modes of standing waves

Tags: waves

If you induce a higher mode in a standing wave, does the wave then carry more energy? If so, does that differ for a mechanical or EM wave?

(Perhaps I should elaborate on why I am asking this question: I’m a beginner at studying quantum mechanics, and with the wave-particle duality, electrons are said to be standing waves about the nucleus, with their principal quantum number analogous to the mode of the standing wave. Obviously a greater principal quantum number means higher energy. So does that mean a standing wave has more energy when it is in a higher mode?)

Answer (score 1):

A standing wave is a mode of vibration.  One can use the concept of increasing the mode when one visualizes the electron shells of an atom.  The quantum number of an electron shell describes the wave properties of an electron, and corresponds to the energy state of an electron within the atom.  The Bohr model of the atom assigned a principal quantum number to each quantized energy state which an electron could occupy, corresponding to the size of the "orbital" and the number of standing waves which could fit into the orbital (or shell).  Higher quantum numbers signify larger shells farther from the nucleus, which can accommodate greater numbers of standing waves, and a greater number of electrons.

Quantum numbers must be integers, Bohr reasoned, because only an integer number of wavelengths could occupy a space and be in the mode of a standing wave (as explained below with regard to mechanical standing waves).  Electrons which occupy shells closer to the nucleus have lower principal quantum numbers.  Additional energy is required to accommodate an electron in an outer shell of greater size with greater quantum number, a greater number of wavelengths, and more electrons.

So, yes, inducing a higher mode of electron vibration within the atom results in the electron carrying more energy.  This may be accomplished if an incoming photon energizes an electron.  Conversely, if an electron emits a photon and drops to a lower energy state, it falls into a shell closer to the nucleus with smaller principal quantum number.

Actually, electrons do not occupy orbits or shells.  They are in quantum states.  But that  could be a subject for another question.

Here is a macro description of standing waves:  A standing wave can be a mode of vibration whereby a wave is reflected back on itself, and the reflection is thrown 180 degrees out of phase with the incident wave, resulting in constructive interference, and the appearance of a wave roughly double the amplitude of the incident wave, but appearing to stand still.  It's really a traveling wave, but because the reflection changes phase, it looks like there is just one wave frozen in place.  Here is an illustration and a better explanation: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/standw.html.

A similar phenomenon can occur in EMF waves.  Here is a description of an experiment which induces standing waves by bouncing radio waves off a metal sheet: http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~lecturedemonstrations/Composer/Pages/76.10.html.  Scroll down to the paragraph titled **Standing waves**.  The description points out that the distance traversed by the standing wave must correspond exactly with an integer multiple of a fraction of the wavelength, or there will be no standing wave.

Before considering an electron in an atom, let us consider increasing the mode of a mechanical wave in a [dispersive medium](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/Dispersion/dispersion.html) by increasing the integer number of standing waves occupying a fixed length of string, for example.  By increasing the mode, you increase the energy stored by that string.  But in order to fit more wavelengths in a dispersive medium such as a fixed length of string, you must increase the velocity of the standing wave.  As a standing wave stores kinetic energy, the equation for kinetic energy is useful:

$E = (1/2) * m * v^2$

$E$ is kinetic energy in joules

$m$ is mass in kilograms

$v$ is velocity in meters per second (the propagation velocity)

Wavelength and frequency in a uniformly propagating wave are inversely related to each other.  Increase one and the other must decrease.  Therefore, in order to store more energy in a dispersive medium such as a fixed length of string, you must increase the velocity.

**But** the velocity of the electron standing wave in an atom can **not** increase.  So the only way to accommodate more energetic electrons is for them to jump to a larger shell able to accommodate a greater number of standing waves.  In an atom, the velocity of an electron remains c, so a more energetic electron shell must contain more standing waves (more electrons)

The standing wave of an electron in an atom is 3-dimensional, rather than 2-dimensional.  Increasing the mode of vibration of the electrons in an atom increases the energy of the electrons, which jump to larger shells able to accommodate a greater number of standing waves.

Comment: Thank you, but I do mean modes. I know that amplitude and energy are related. I have redacted my question if it helps make things clearer.

Comment: @stygian: I edited my answer to address your revised question.  Quantum numbers can be thought of as modes of vibration of the wave quality of electrons.

Comment: Why is it, though, that increasing the integer number of standing waves occupying a fixed length of string increases the energy transported by that string? Is there a mathematical rationale for this?

Comment: Your statment "But in order to fit more wavelengths on to a fixed length of string, you must increase the velocity of the standing wave." is not true. You can have standing wave modes in a non-dispersive medium. The propagation velocity is the same for all modes. Higher modes have higher frequency and so, shorter wavelengths. So you can fit more wavelengths on the same length of string.  As your comments about kinetic energy are based on the false assumption that velocity is larger for higher modes, you should make some changes there too.

Comment: nasu:  Yes, you are right.  I did some research, thought about this, and will make changes soon.  Thank you!